# :Django: URL dispatcher doesn't convert DateField to '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, django, datefield

UPD: I was debugging and found that in `Class PubDateConverter` in `to_url` value of `value` is empty. Just nothing and I don't know why...

I'm a newbie with Django and I'm faced with a problem — can't convert string to datetime object and back with `register_converter`.

I have a date as *Jan 1, 2000* and I need to convert to *2000-01-01*. I created converter, registered it, but in the template, I see the date as *Jan 1, 2000*.

How could I fix it?

That's `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from datetime import datetime

class PubDateConverter:
    regex = r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
    format = '%Y-%m-%d'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return datetime.strptime(value, self.format)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return value.strftime(self.format)

register_converter(PubDateConverter, 'date')


urlpatterns = [
    path('books/<date:pub_date>/', book_view, name='book_view'),
]
```

That's `models.py`:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=64)
    author = models.CharField('Author', max_length=64)
    pub_date = models.DateField('Pub_date')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.author
```

That's `views.py`:

```
def book_list(request):
    return render(request, 'books/book_list.html', {'book_list': Book.objects.all()})
```

And in template I substitute the value as:

```
{% for book in book_list %}
    <p>Date: {{ book.pub_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I use Django version is `Django==4.0.5`

Comment: Converters affect the resolving and reversing of url patterns, do you want to format all dates rendered in template variables too?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, I need to display the already converted value into the template and create a link to get an address like _/books/2000-01-01_ and data about this object

Comment: @IainShelvington I was debugging and found that in Class PubDateConverter in to_url value of value is empty. Just nothing and I don't know why...

Comment: Does modifying this setting `DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'` work for you? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#date-format

Comment: @IainShelvington I was doing it, but, unfortunately, nope. Seems, I have an error in the converter class, but everything seems to be ok there...

Answer (score 0):

Register converter do convert the field, but only in the url context:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#register-converter

In the response you get the orginal `book` objects (see the response in the browser). You can modify the response by creating `BookView`

```
  from django.views.generic import DetailView
  
  class BookView(DetailView):

    queryset = Book.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        obj.pub_date_str = obj.pub_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        return obj
```

and then return it in the patter:
`path('books/<date:pub_date>/', BookView.as_view(), name='book_view')`

PS. It is not tested, it is just an idea.

Comment: Hmm, now I tried Register Converter with only url path and get an error `'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`, in template it as `{% url 'book_view' book_view.pub_date %}`

How can I fix hyperlink and get data for current object with converted url?

Comment: maybe try to use pub_date_str everywhere, I am not sure, but I know you will figure it out, ;)

Comment: I was debugging and found that in Class PubDateConverter in to_url value of value is empty. Just nothing and I don't know why...

Comment: I suppose you typed `{% url 'book_view' book_view.pub_date_str %}` and the `pub_date_str` is empty in this case ... So maybe try to use pub_date_str but not everywhere ;)

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, it also doesn't work — I was trying and with `_str_` and without `_str_`